# How can i insert multiple textboxes value in my database, using dynamic text fields

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building form with dynamic textboxes, if you click at the button "add", it appears a new textbox, i'm using php and javascript.

But i just can add into my database the value from the first textbox.

How can i insert multiple values into my database?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript"><!--
         $(document).ready(function(){

         var counter = 2;
         $("#add").click(function () {
         if(counter==11){
             alert("Too many boxes");
             return false;
         }   
             $("#textBoxes").append("<div id='d"+counter+"' ><label for='t2'> Textbox "+counter+"</label><input     type='textbox' id='t"+counter+"' > </div>\n");
             ++counter;
         });

         $("#remove").click(function () {
         if(counter==1){
             alert("No boxes");
             return false;
         }   
             --counter;
             $("#d"+counter).remove();
         });
         });
         // --></script>
      </head>
      <body>


            <form method="POST">
        <div id='textBoxes'>
            <label for="t1"> Textbox 1</label>
            <input name="nome" type='textbox' id='t1' ></div>
         </div>

         <input type='button' value='add' id='add'>
         <input type='button' value='remove' id='remove'>
         <input type='submit' name="adicionar" value='adicionar'>
         </form>
         <?php
            $dbHost = 'localhost';
                       $dbUsername = 'hr';
                       $dbPassword = '';
                       $dbDatabase = 'r_inserir';

                       $db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
                       mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

            if(isSet($_POST['adicionar']))
            {

            $nome=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']);

            $sql=  mysql_query("INSERT INTO registos(nome) values ('".$nome."')");
            }
            ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the name like this in html:

```
<input name="nome[]" type='textbox' id='t1' ></div>
```

then in you javascript:

```
$("#textBoxes").append("<div id='d"+counter+"' ><label for='t2'> Textbox "+counter+"</label><input name='nome[]' type='textbox' id='t"+counter+"' > </div>\n");
```

these code return the array data into your php file. then insert it you your database.

```
if(isset($_POST['adicionar']))
        {

        //$nome=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']);
        foreach($_POST['nome'] as $nome){
              mysql_query("INSERT INTO registos(nome) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($nome)."')");
        }

        //$sql=  mysql_query("INSERT INTO registos(nome) values ('".$nome."')");
        }
```

### Important:

**This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.**

Comment: you have typo in `isSet()`

Comment: @user3429726 oops my type error, should be `as`, check the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must have dynamic names for the input fields along with ids, secondly loop through all the input values fetched from post and then save it.

e.g:

```
<input type='textbox' id='t"+counter+"' name='name"+counter+"' >
```

and then use $_POST['name'], $_POST['name1'] and so on to store it in database.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but you can let the form send the text fields as an array:

```
<input type="text" name="nome[]" ... />
```

Then you can access this array in PHP using:

```
<?php
    $_POST['nome'] //array containing all the values
?>
```

Finally, you can store this array serialized in the database. Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

```
<?php
//when you store the data
$nome=mysql_real_escape_string( serialize ($_POST['nome']) );
//....

//when you retrieve the data
$nomes = unserialize($row['nome']); //(for example, returns array with all names)
?>
```

**Important:** When using serialized content, you might change the MySQL field type to TEXT instead of VARCHAR because it could be a very long string.

**Appendix:** You should also use **mysqli** instead of **mysql**!